# Rotating List <Character> and maintaining word number

Tags: java, string, arraylist, rotation

I am trying to rotate a string to the right line by line (input coming from a file). The input could potentially have many lines, so the rotation needs to happen per line.

For example, rotating this to the right by 5
`and line breaks^$@` 
would end up being: `^$@ and line breaks`.

I'm working with a `List<String>` and have done the following:

```
 private static List<String> rflag(String value, List<String> lines) {
    List<String> newLines = new ArrayList<>();

    int rvalue = Integer.parseInt(value);

    for (String line : lines) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (!line.isEmpty()) {
            List <Character> chars=  new ArrayList<>();

            for(char ch: line.toCharArray()){
                chars.add(ch);
            }

            Collections.rotate(chars, rvalue);

            sb.append(chars);
            String text = sb.toString()
                    .replace(",", "")  //remove the commas
                    .replace("[", "")  //remove the right bracket
                    .replace("]", "")  //remove the left bracket
                    .trim();
            newLines.equals(text);
        }
    }
    return newLines;
}
```

If I input something like `abcXYZ`, my output ends up being `[b, c, X, Y, Z, a]` or `bcXYZa` with the removal of brackets and commas.

My main problem is that, while I can remove the brackets and commas, I'm not preserving the lines or words in an input.

Comment: What is the purpose of `newLines.equals(text);` ?

Comment: I think I was just trying different things. Can be ignored. Originally I had it as newLines.add(sb.toString());

Comment: @Grimby can you just provide your sample input and expected output and the output that you are getting?

Comment: Sure. If the input is: "and line breaks^$@" , the output currently is "^ $ @   a n d   l i n e   b r e a k s"  but it should be "^$@ and line breaks". So as you can see the rotation is correct, but the spacing is off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing

```
.replace(",", "")  //remove the commas
```

to

```
.replace(", ", "")  //remove the commas
```

makes this code work as you expect it.

```
System.out.println(rflag("2", Arrays.asList("and line breaks"))); //output: ksand line brea
```

(`and line breaks^$@` , the output currently is `^ $ @ a n d l i n e b r e a k s` but it should be `^$@ and line breaks`.)

Comment: hahaha i think this is it! i'll give it a go in a bit- it's late now so will try again in the morning :) Thanks lots!